# How do I make only certain nav links clickable in bootstrap site?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navigation

I used bootstrap in my web application, how do I make the current page link non-clickable in the nav bar?

I want to include the same heading on each page but only allow the Site name to be clickable because that will link to the home page.

[image]

So in my example the **HOME** text will not be clickable and will not get highlighted on hover but **TEST SITE** will be clickable and have the hover effect.

Is there a way to format to achieve this?

**EDIT**

```
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Main.aspx">Test Site | Home</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
```

And here is the relevant css:

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

    .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-brand:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        display: block;
        width: 22px;
        height: 2px;
        border-radius: 1px;
    }

        .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bootply or fiddle demonstrating this issue would be helpful. I have no idea what your code looks like. http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: The answer is to wrap each section in its own `<a>` tag linking to separate pages, and to have these links dynamically generate based on the current page. Can you include some of your code so we can see how to accomplish this in context?

Comment: Do you want to add a text `span` after the `a.navbar-brand` link and have it formatted to match the non-hover look of the `.navbar-brand`?

Comment: @MikeLyons, I added the html code. I will work on the bootply sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just wrap the navbar sections in separate tags one in an `<a>` and one with a `<span>` both with the `navbar-brand` class

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="../Main.aspx">Test Site</a><span class="navbar-brand"> | Home</span>
```

Comment: I did that but the formatting from the navbar-brand is gone when it is out of the class

Comment: can you add the css for that to your question?

Comment: added the css to my question

Comment: Yeah looks like you could just wrap the Test Site in an `<a>` with the class `navbar-brand` and wrap the Home in a `span` with that class. Answer updated.